# How to Unit Test the FilePostRedirectGet plugin?

Tags: unit-testing, plugins, zend-framework2, phpunit

TLDR:

How to write an integration test for a [FilePostRedirectGet](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#file-post-redirect-get-plugin) form submission request?

---

In my application I have a multi-page form with a file element in it. Originally the controller code was (psuedo code - all multi-page stuff removed):

```
$form = new MyForm();
if($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
  if($form->isValid($this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
    //move file to new home and save post to database.
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('admin/cms/edit');
  }
}
return new ViewModel(['form' => $form]);
```

Very basically, if the form was valid it would save the form details and perform a redirect (typically the edit version of the page). If the form was not valid, it would just show the form again with the appropriate error messages.

The problem with this approach, is if one of the form elements fails validation, the file input will lose its value and the user will need to re-upload their file. To get around this, I changed to the FPRG approach:

```
$form = new MyForm();
/* @var $prg FilePostRedirectGet */
$prg = $this->filePostRedirectGet($form, $this->url()->fromRoute($this->routeMatch, ['action' => $this->action, 'id' => $id], ['query' => ['page' => $page]]), true);
if ($prg instanceof Response) {
  return $prg; // Return PRG redirect response
} elseif ($prg !== false) {
    //move file to new home and save post to database.
    return $this->redirect()->toRoute('admin/cms/edit');
}
return new ViewModel(['form' => $form]);
```

The `FilePostRedirectGet` plugin saves the post data in a session, redirects to the same page, validates the form and, if valid, redirects to the success/edit page - otherwise just show the form with errors. The benefits of this approach is that the file input retains its value regardless of any other failed elements.

The problem is, how to write an integration test for this request?

Originally, there was only one redirect (on success) so I could test for that (model mocking stuff removed for brevity):

```
/**
 * Redirect to next page after form submission.
 */
public function testAddActionRedirectsAfterValidPost() {

    $postData = $this->_postData();

    $this->dispatch('http://localhost/admin/cms/add', 'POST', $postData);
    $this->assertResponseStatusCode(302);
    $this->assertRedirectTo('http://localhost/admin/cms/edit/13');

    return $postData;
}
```

However, due to the multiple redirects, I cannot use this method of testing if the request was successful or not.

How to write an integration test for this request?

Comment: The initial problem you encountered seems to get from using `getPost()` without the `$_FILES` merged in. Uploads will not be available in `getPost()` and that's why you were missing them. https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.form.file-upload.html#the-controller-action  approach with saving files in a session could end up as a security breach, because you save a file even if the form is not valid, so it could be anything residing on your server then. I would say it is not a good idea 

Comment: Psuedo code. Also - the FPRG is a ZF2 plugin which validates the file in the form before saving the valid contents into session. If the file is not valid, it is not saved. 
https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#file-post-redirect-get-plugin

Comment: I feel as though you have misunderstood the original question. The question is NOT about uploading files and validating the form. It is about using the FilePostRedirectGet plugin (https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.form.file-upload.html#file-post-redirect-get-plugin) and writing integration tests against this controller / plugin.

Comment: @RichardParnaby-King it would be helpful if you can elaborate on this statement '_However, due to the multiple redirects, I cannot use this method of testing if the request was successful or not._' For e.g what was the workflow of all the URLs from start to end, in previous setup which worked and in the current setup which is not working. I am also assuming that you are only checking for valid post data, which is to say $postData does have valid data that will pass.